# Mesh Changes Shape when Parenting Armature

Tags: armature

My low poly character's chest and arms changes shape when parenting armature with automatic weights.

I don't know what is going on and here is the file. Just simply parent armature to cube(modified into low poly character). [Link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/3jn0gs16dgqvq2d/Character.blend/file)

[image: Default character]

But when I parent the armature,

[image: After parenting]

This happens. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, bend a bit the elbow in *Edit* mode so that Blender knows in what direction the arm is supposed to bend:

[image]

Now correct the *IK Pole Angle* value, for example the correct value for left arm is -90°:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked!